# Asymptotic formula for $\# \{ n^{1/k} \in [N,2N] : n \in \mathbb{N}, \, k \in \mathbb{N}, k \leq K \}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Fix $K \in \mathbb{N}$. Let 
$$
A_K(N) = \{ n^{1/k} \in [N,2N]: n \in \mathbb{N}, \, k \in \mathbb{N}, k \leq K \}.
$$
What is the cardinality of 
$$
A_K(N)
$$
for large $N$?

Case $K = 2$:
$$
\# A_2(N) = \# \{n \in [N,2N] : n \in \mathbb{N} \} + \# \{n^{1/2} \in [N,2N] : n \in \mathbb{N}, n \text{ is not a square }\}
$$
The first term is $\simeq N$. The second term is 
\begin{align}
&=\#\{N^2 \leq n \leq (2N)^2 : n \in \mathbb{N}, n \text{ is not a square } \} \\
&=\#\{N^2 \leq n \leq (2N)^2 : n \in \mathbb{N}\} - \#\{N^2 \leq n \leq (2N)^2 : n \in \mathbb{N}, n \text{ is  a square } \} \\
&\simeq N^2 - (N^2)^{1/2} \\
&\simeq N^2.
\end{align}
So 
$$
\# A_2(N) \simeq N + N^2 \simeq N^2.
$$

Based on this, I'd guess $\#A_K(N) \simeq N^K$.

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For each fixed $k$, the set 
 $$  B_k:=\{ n^{1/k} \in [N,2N]: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$ 
is in bijective correspondence with  $ \{ n  \in [N^k,(2N)^k]: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. The latter has $\lfloor (2N)^k\rfloor - \lfloor N^k\rfloor+1$ element, which is $\simeq N^k$.

The cardinality of the union $\bigcup_{k\le K}B_k$ is at least $|B_K|\simeq N^K$ and at most  $$\sum_{k=1}^K |B_k| \lesssim \sum_{k=1}^K N^k \le N^K(1-1/N)^{-1} \simeq N^K$$  Hence, it is $\simeq N^K$.